# How to merge queries in Excel by joining Multiple Lines in a table to One in another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a metrics data by merging 2 queries into 1 in Excel 2015. Incident ID is the primary key field joining the 2 tables which will duplicate in Table 1 but not in Table 2. I want to merge the queries in such a way that Fields from first line of every Incident should merge with the single line in Table 2.

Table 1:

```
Ref No Action Date
------------------
A1     01/01/2019      --> (Want this data in output)
A1     02/01/2019
A1     03/01/2019
A2     02/01/2019      --> (Want this data in output)
A2     03/01/2019
```

Table 2:

```
Ref No Closed Date
------------------
A1     04/01/2019
A2     05/01/2019
```

Output:

```
Ref No   Action Date  Closed Date
----------------------------------
A1       01/01/2019   04/01/2019
A2       02/01/2019   05/01/2019
```

Comment: Is the first line always the oldest date for that particular incident?

Comment: Yes... First line will always have the oldes date for a Ref value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you either meant Excel 2013 or Excel 2016. In either case you would have access to PowerQuery. Below is an example on how you could approach this using this fine tool:

- Select Table2 > `Data` tab > Data `From Table/Range`
- In PQ > `File` > `Close and Load To` > Select `Only Create Connection` > `OK`
- Select Table1 > 'Data' tab > 'Get Data' Dropdown > `Combine Queries` > `Merge`

Now in this merge menu:

- At the top select Table1, at the bottom select Table2
- Highlight the `Ref No` column
- For `Type Join` choose `Left Outer (all from first, matching from second)`

While mine is in Dutch, it should look similar to:

[image]

- Hit `OK`

Now in the PQ editor you'll notice an extra column, e.g: `Table2`:

[image]

- Click the double pointed arrow in the header
- Uncheck `Ref No`
- Hit `OK`

The column data will now show all `Closed date` with it's appropriate `Action Date`:

[image]

With the new `Closed date` column still selected:

- Under `Start` tab > `Remove Rows` dropdown > `Remove Duplicates`

The output would look like:

[image]

If you want to, you can optionally:

- Select both `Date` columns > `Transform Tab` > `Date` dropdown > `Only Date`
- Double click `Closed Date` column header > Change header name > Type `Closed Date`

[image]

Now exit PQ and save your work :)

[image]

---

And yes, this can also be done through formulas.